# List all image on folder and subfolder and add <a name=" "> for each change folder use php

Tags: php

i want add`<a name="each folder change">`

try`<a name="'$directory'">` front `<img`

by use this

```
$directory = "test/*/";

foreach (glob($directory.'*') as $image) {

echo '<img class="img-responsive" src="' . $image . '"/>';

}
```

and i try have some result like this

```
<a name="img"><img class="img-responsive" src="test/img/img-000.jpg"></a>

<img class="img-responsive" src="test/img/img-001.jpg">

<a name="image"><img class="img-responsive" src="test/image/image-001.png"></a>

<img class="img-responsive" src="test/image/image-002.png">
```

Comment: `basename(dirname($image))`

Comment: So like this `echo '<a name="basename(dirname($image))><img class="img-responsive" src="' . $image . '"/></a>';`

Comment: end result like this if use that
`<div id="all" style=""><a name="basename(dirname($image))"><img class="img-responsive" src="test/img/img-000.jpg"></a></div>`